# Divergence proof problem in introductory analysis text.

Tags: analysis, divergent-series

The problem is this:

> Show that if $a_n > 0$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} na_n = L$ with $L \neq 0$, then the series $\sum a_n$ diverges.
>   (from Abbott's *Understanding Analysis*, p. 68).

I want someone to correct my proof if it is wrong.

### My proof:

Since $(\forall \epsilon >0)(\exists N\in \mathbb N)(\forall n\ge N)|na_n - L|＜\epsilon$ is given, $(\forall n\ge N) L-\epsilon_0 < na_n < L+\epsilon_0$.

And assumed $N \neq  0$, $(\forall n \ge N) \frac{L-\epsilon_0}{n} < a_n < \frac{L+\epsilon_0}{n}$.

Then, let $\epsilon_0 = L - 1$. Then, we get $1/n < a_n < (2L-1)/n$.

Since $1/n < a_n$, by Comparison Test, $\sum a_n$ diverges.

---

Since the solution from the author is different from mine, I suspect whether there is a wrong step. I wasn't fully confident with defining e_0, but I have no idea whether it is correct or not.

Thank you!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I immediately recognize that L-1 has no garantee of being positive. Then what would be good candidates?

Comment: Dear Shaun, I really appreciate your comment! I will learn it as quickly as possible.

Comment: You can use $\epsilon_0 = L/2$.